# Producer-consumer with side constraints in Kafka (or others)

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, producer-consumer

We have a bunch of producers that send messages/events to a bunch of consumers. Each message must be consumed by exactly one consumer. We know that this common scenario can easily be achieved by using consumer groups in Kafka. However, we also have a couple of additional constraints: Not every consumer can consume every message. Messages have (arbitrary) requirements attached to them and only consumers that fulfil these requirements must process them. This would still be possible with a consumer group where a consumer first looks at the message and eventually re-submits it if it does not meet the requirements. However, there is no guarantee that messages will be seen by every consumers at least once so they may bounce around indefinitely although there may be a matching consumer. We also cannot set up multiple topics because the requirements for consumers are arbitrary complex boolean formulas defined by the user and not the application. This can result in a combinatorial explosion of topics.

Additionally we want to be able to dynamically add and remove consumers from the group in case more processing resources are needed. As far as I understood Kafka, this can lead to consumers not getting any messages if there are not enough partitions and dynamically re-partitioning is also not really possible (without admin interaction).

Is there any way to make this work in Kafka? Maybe Kafka is also not the right technology, are there others that are more suitable? We also looked at RabbitMQ but also there we did not find a way that guarantees that every consumer is seeing a message so that it can evaluate the requirements.

Comment: Questions about software recommendations are unfortunately off-topic on Stackoverflow. If you have a specific question on Kafka we might be able to support. But this is not the right place to do architectural comparisons. I recommend to focus on one technology, explain your use case as you already did, and finally ask a specific question about the one technology.

Answer (score 0):

you could commit offsets manually when you after identifying the desired events by setting ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG to false in your consumer configs but your use-case would trigger excessive rebalances which stops any consumption. i don't think Kafka is the appropriate infrastructure for this.

however if you could mark your events with finite number of keys, you can dictate which partition they are produced to. using the same key in your consumer guarantees to poll events from the same partition. note that you need to have the same number of partitions in your topic as the number of unique keys.